# Deleting Specific controls in an c# form

Tags: c#, forms

When I click a button I want to delete that particular flowlayout panel along with the check box and the button itself.But I have no clue how to do this. 
Here is my code to do this:

```
    private static CheckBox _taskCompletionCheckBox;

    public static void DisplaySingleTask(LayoutType layoutType, FlowLayoutPanel layoutPanel,TodoItem item)
    {
        //creates a panel
        var parentPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel {Parent = layoutPanel, AutoSize = true, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle};

        //Based on layout type, the panel's content's are determined
        switch (layoutType)
        {
            case LayoutType.Small:
                _taskCompletionCheckBox = new CheckBox {Parent = parentPanel, Dock = DockStyle.Left,Text = item.Name,AutoSize = true,BackColor = Color.Transparent};
                _taskCompletionCheckBox.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
                _taskCompletionCheckBox.Show();
                var delBtn = new Button { Parent = parentPanel, Dock = DockStyle.Left, Size = new Size(30, _taskCompletionCheckBox.Size.Width),Image = Resources.DeleteTaskImage};
                delBtn.Click += delBtn_Click;

                break;
            case LayoutType.Normal:
                break;
            case LayoutType.Full:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("layoutType");
        }
    }

    static void delBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I would like to know how can I get a reference to the the flowlayout panel here so I can call the dispose() method on it.
    }
```

Comment: The problem is I cannot figure out how to get a reference to its specific flowlayoutparent.

Comment: There are two types of controls.  One that is added by using the designer, and the other by adding controls with your own code.  If you delete a control that is added by the designed it will not get permanently deleted.  If you want to temporarily remove a control it it is better to set the Visible property to 'false'.

Comment: I want to delete this because other panels will come in its places

Comment: Instead of deleting I think you should just create a new instance of the layout panel. FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have got your point, the FlawLayoutPanel you are looking for is parent of the button. Cast the sender parameter of the event handler to button and get it's parent.

```
static void delBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button button = (Button)sender;
     FlowLayoutPanel panel = (FlowLayoutPanel)button.Parent;
     // ..
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the perfect answer. However this is deleting the most newly created instance and not the one in which I click the button

Comment: get the parent of the object (let the name be "myControlElement") you want to delete. and then call control.Controls.Remove(myControlElement);

Comment: EDIT: The correct instance is now getting deleted Thank you very much @JensHorstmann and Mehrzad Chehraz